# MvvM Light Toolkit Certificate Error

Tags: mvvm-light

I recently installed the MvvM Light Toolkit and created the default Windows 8.1 XAML Application Project Template.

When I compile it I get the following warnings:

"Warning 6 Certificate file 'MvvmLight.Win8_TemporaryKey.pfx' not found. MvvmLight1" 
 "Warning 7 The certificate specified is not valid for signing. For more information about valid certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478. MvvmLight1"

I am unable to build an application package with these errors present and I am unable to side-load the project to test it on other boxes.

If I create a default Windows 8.1 XAML not using the MvvM Light template, it works and compiles fine. I can build an application package with no issues and side-load the app correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you properly installed the toolkit or just added some references (DLLs)?

Comment: I downloaded the toolkit from "http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/" and installed it.  Then created the default Win8.1 XAML project and built it.

Comment: Note: I just built the MvvM Light v8.0 XAML project and it builds correctly with no warnings or errors building the app package.

Answer (score 0):

Renew the certificate:

1. In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the .appxmanifest file, choose Open With, and then choose App Manifest Designer.
2. In the App Manifest Designer, choose the Packaging tab, and then choose the Choose Certificate button.
3. In the Choose Certificate dialog box, expand the Configure Certificate list, and then choose Create test certificate.
4. In the Create test certificate dialog box, click the OK button.